# Unable to use Screen efficiently in Mac's Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, gnu-screen

The post summarizes problems in using Screen in Mac's terminal when you have the following in your .zshrc

```
if [[ $STY = '' ]] then screen -xR; fi
```

1. **[Solution #1 is not working but Solution #2 works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810025/unable-to-use-screen-efficiently-in-macs-terminal/810395#810395):** Clipboard programs: pbcopy, pbpaste and xsel do not work at all
2. Bug in Vim when used in Mac: [Unable to have no scattered windows in Screen by .Xresources.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809935/unable-to-solve-a-bug-in-vims-tlist-with-screen/809975#809975)
3. **[Solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810025/unable-to-use-screen-efficiently-in-macs-terminal/810069#810069):** Ctrl A stops working in terminal. This suggests me that Screen's keyboard bindings need to be changed slightly.
4. **[Solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810025/unable-to-use-screen-efficiently-in-macs-terminal/3423480#3423480):** The scrolling with touchpad does not work. By editing your .screenrc the scrollback works normally (including touchpad)
5. **[Solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815915/unable-to-bind-hjkl-to-dlth-in-screens-c-a-esc-mode)**: Unable to have Dvorak keybindings for Screen for moving in Scrollback mod.
6. [How can you use pbcopy/pbpaste/xsel inside Screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816302/unable-to-pbcopy-xsel-inside-screen)

Comment: By the way, shouldn't this question probably be on serverfault.com? It now has a beta that's open to anyone who has a rep on stackoverflow of at least 100.

Comment: No, I think this would be more appropriate to be on superuser.com
Great question anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually solve the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> problem by setting my escape character to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> (which you generally don't need to use as often when you're running screen, since instead of backgrounding a process, you can just start up a new screen). In my `.screenrc`:

```
escape ^Zz
```

Scrolling using the touchpad just isn't going to work; screen is acting as a terminal emulator inside a terminal emulator, and it's just not possible for screen to switch the scrollback buffer in Terminal.app whenever you switch between screens. You're going to have to use screen's scrollback features. See [this article](http://www.samsarin.com/blog/2007/03/11/gnu-screen-working-with-the-scrollback-buffer/) for some tips on using screen's scrollback features.

Comment: +1... I use ctrl-z too.  It's really not a problem due to how infrequently you actually type ctrl-z relative to other stuff.

Comment: Scrollback works just fine in Putty.  It's Terminal that's broken, not screen.

Answer (score 36):

In `screenrc`:

```
# Make xterm scrolling work properly with screen.
termcapinfo xterm-256color|xterm-color|xterm|xterms|xs|rxvt ti@:te@
```

Works for Terminal.app too.

Comment: Wow! This is great! Work like a charm with Terminal.app.

Comment: Just what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 1):

The default OS X Terminal app is weak.  Get iTerm instead:

[iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/)

If I'm not mistaken, iTerm solves all of these out of the box (my install is a couple years old, so I can't test that theory now).

Answer (score 1):

Problem #3 might be solvable if you enable the alternate screen buffer. Use `altscreen on` in `.screenrc`

Comment: @staticsan: The next problem is to know how to do that. I did not find the result by Google.

Comment: man screen will tell you where it will look for .screenrc. If it doesn't exist, create one. Incidentally, man screen is a wealth of information. I often find out something new every time I read it.

Comment: Oh  yes - you can try out screen commands by doing cmd-colon (defaults to Ctrl+A then :). This gives you a little command line to enter screen directives.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution #1 which does not work**

To be able to copy/paste in OSX put the following to your .screenrc

```
bind b eval "writebuf" "exec sh -c 'pbcopy < /tmp/screen-exchange'"
```

[> Th[e] line - - sends that file to pbcopy - -.](http://www.samsarin.com/blog/2007/03/11/gnu-screen-working-with-the-scrollback-buffer/)

The command is bound to C-a b (in my case, C-z b).

**Solution #2 which works but is rather slow to type**

Use Scrollback mode i.e. copy mode by

Coping

```
C-A [
```

Pasting

```
C-A ]
```

The solution is great, since it is the same in all terminal apps. It is similar to the clipboard as you use with your mouse.

Comment: I do not know how you can use the command with pbcopy. I run unsuccessfully $ echo Masi | pbcopy C-z b.

Answer (score 0):

> Q5: Impossible: The scrolling with
>   touchpad does not work.

You can use ^A Esc to scroll up the screen. You cannot use Touchpad in Screen.

Answer (score 0):

This solves the scrollback issue, although it is somewhat broken in that it isn't aware of screen's buffers.
`env TERM=vt100 screen`

Comment: I put the line to my .zshrc. The command caused my Screen to duplicate screen buffers a lot (endless loop) such that I could access my terminal anymore. --- The loop starts again if I go to the buffer #0. --- It seeems that the code's purpose is to be used without Screen.

Comment: If you want it in your .zshrc then use this.
`if [[ $STY = '' ]] then env TERM=vt100 screen; fi`