# Unable to bind HJKL to DLTH in Screen's C-A Esc -mode

Tags: binding, zsh, gnu-screen, dvorak

I want my Zsh to be Dvorak friendly in Screen.

I am trying to make the following bindings in Zsh such that I can use them in Ctl-a Esc mode in moving

```
h => d
j => l
k => t
l => n
```

I have not yet found any ways to do that.

**How can you make the following keybindings in Screen**, such that I can use them in the mode C-A Esc?

Comment: Are you referring to screen's Ctrl+A Esc mode?

Comment: @Greg: Yes exactly: I am referring to screen's in Ctrl+A Esc mode in Zsh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Screen has a [`markkeys`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Copy-Mode-Keys.html#Copy-Mode-Keys) configuration option that lets you remap the keys used in scrollback mode.

The following code makes Screen Dvorak friendly in .screenrc

```
 markkeys h=d:j=h:k=t:l=n
```