# Unable to use Screen's clipboard inside Firefox

Tags: firefox, clipboard, gnu-screen

I have not managed to get my pbcopy/pbpaste to work in Screen as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816302/unable-to-pbcopy-xsel-inside-screen).

I aim to solve the problem by having Screen clipboard inside Firefox.
Its paste works in terminal by the following command but not in Firefox

```
C-a ]
```

**How can you use Screen's clipboard inside Firefox?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that makes use of screen's buffer-writing commands and `pbcopy`:

- [Copying the GNU screen buffer to the Leopard clipboard](http://www.samsarin.com/blog/2008/10/18/copying-gnu-screen-buffer-to-leopard-clipboard/)

Answer (score 0):

Screen's clipboard (correctly called a paste buffer) only works inside that instance of screen. That's all it's designed to do.

The best way to copy-n-paste to FireFox is to use your terminal program's copy mechanism.