# pbcopy does not seem to work within a gnu screen window in OSX

Tags: macos, gnu, gnu-screen

On my OS X Leopard Macbook Pro, I try to pipe text or redirect a text file into `pbcopy`. It works when I do this in the Terminal, but not if I do it in the Terminal when I'm working in a Gnu screen window.

Is this a bug or is there a workaround?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/810025/unable-to-use-screen-efficiently-in-macs-terminal and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816302/unable-to-have-pbcopy-clipboard-inside-screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Known bug](http://trac.macports.org/ticket/18235).  It may be fixed in Snow Leopard.